# props in undefined components using redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, components

I just starting react and I understand the difference between props and state. But what I don't get is when I import a component I can set the component value with the props. However the setting the titel is no problem. Who can help me out the name props can be set. In my case it says undefined.

I can fix it with a statement fotos.tags has value show component. Is there also an other way? The problem is the  and the foto.tags. In the component this.props.name is undefined.

```
    import React from 'react';
    import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';
    import {connect} from 'react-redux';
    import * as actions from '../../../reducers/fotoboek/fotos/actions.js';
    import Tags from '../../../Components/Fotoboek/form/tags.jsx';
    class FotoItem extends React.Component {
      state = {
        tags:[]
      }
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
      }

      componentWillMount() {
        this.props.fetchfotosItem(this.props.match.params.item);
      }

      handleChange = (e) => {
        this.setState({
          [e.target.name]: e.target.value
        });
        this.setState
      }
      GetTags = (event) => {
        this.setState({ tags: event});
      }

The file 
  GetTheme = (event) => {
    this.setState({ themes: event});
  }

  render() {
    const {fotos} = this.props;
    return (
      <div className="container">
<span><fotos.titel/span>
        <Tags name={fotos.tags} GetTags={this.GetTags}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {fotos: state.fotos.item}
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, actions)(FotoItem);
```

The file '../../../Components/Fotoboek/form/tags.jsx';

```
import React, {Component, PropTypes} from 'react'
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import * as actions from '../../../reducers/fotoboek/tags/actions.js';
import Select from 'react-select';
import 'react-select/dist/react-select.css';

class Tags extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      tags: this.props.name
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchtags();
  }

  updateState(element) {
    this.setState({tags: element});
    this.props.GetTags(element.map(getFullName));
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state.tags);
    return (
      <div className="form-group">
        <label>Tags</label>
      <Select name="tags" options={this.props.tags} labelKey="naam" class="form-control" valueKey="_id" multi value={this.state.tags} onChange={this.updateState.bind(this)}/>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {tags: state.tags}
}
function getFullName(item, index) {
    var fullname = [item._id].join(" ");
    return fullname;
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, actions)(Tags);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are fetching on componentWillMount the state might not be there when your component renders.

```
render() {
  const {fotos} = this.props;
  if(fotos) {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <span><fotos.titel/span>
        <Tags name={fotos.tags} GetTags={this.GetTags}/>
      </div>
    );
  } else {
    return (
      <span> Loading... </span>
    )
  }
}
```